# Changing column names with paperclip gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a way to change the column names that paperclip uses when generating its database migration? For example, currently a paperclip migration looks like this:

```
class AddAvatarColumnsToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_attachment :users, :avatar
  end

  def self.down
    remove_attachment :users, :avatar
  end
end
```

And it generates the following in the database:

```
avatar_file_name
avatar_file_size
avatar_content_type
avatar_updated_at
```

Ideally I'd like to change the avatar_file_name to correspond to a column in the database called "content". Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Renaming columns, to something else than `<attachment>_<attribute>` will not work in Paperclip.

It mandatorily needs the following 4 attributes for each attachment in the model:

- `<attachment>_file_name`
- `<attachment>_file_size`
- `<attachment>_content_type`
- `<attachment>_updated_at`

Check this post out for a debate on why following a `<attachment>_url` approach might be better than having a separate model for attachment (`<attachment>.url`): [Paperclip and Inheritance (STI)](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!searchin/paperclip-plugin/rename%2420column/paperclip-plugin/0DysMtKr1Ks/qcf-zaWhpKwJ)

Answer (score 1):

For users that leverage S3 or Google Cloud Storage, you may need to move your files to a new directory following on paperclip's file naming scheme.  Here is a sample migration to point you in the right direction:

```
class MovePaperclipAssets < ActiveRecord::Migration                                                              
  def up                                                                                                           

    storage = Fog::Storage::Google.new google_storage_access_key_id: ENV["GOOGLE_ACCESS_KEY_ID"],                      
                                       google_storage_secret_access_key: ENV["GOOGLE_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"]               
    bucket = storage.directories.get('bucket-name')

    bucket.files.each do |file|                                                                                    
      if file.key.starts_with?("original/directory")                                                        
        newfile = file.key.gsub("original/directory","new/directory")              
        file.copy('bucket-name', newfile)                                                             
        file.destroy                                                                                               
      end                                                                                                          
    end  
  end                                                                                                              

  def down    
    storage = Fog::Storage::Google.new google_storage_access_key_id: ENV["GOOGLE_ACCESS_KEY_ID"],                      
                                       google_storage_secret_access_key: ENV["GOOGLE_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"]               
    bucket = storage.directories.get('bucket-name')

    bucket.files.each do |file|                                                                                    
      if file.key.starts_with?("new/directory")                                                        
        newfile = file.key.gsub("new/directory","original/directory")              
        file.copy('bucket-name', newfile)                                                             
        file.destroy                                                                                               
      end                                                                                                          
    end 
  end    
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ruby script/generate migration RenameDatabaseColumn

class RenameDatabaseColumn < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    rename_column :user, :avatar_file_name, :user_file_name
    rename_column :user, :avatar_file_size, :user_file_size
    rename_column :user, :avatar_content_type, :user_content_type
    rename_column :user, :avatar_updated_at, :user_updated_at       
  end

  def self.down
    # rename back if you need or do something else or do nothing
  end
end
```

Just try the migration may be it will work for you. add column name whatever corresponding column name.

Comment: I agree that will definitely change the column names, but will paperclip still know to write to that column in the database after I rename it?

Comment: In your model also change like the below **attr_accessible :user
  has_attached_file :user, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }  and view <%= f.file_field :user %> and** also change  **user**  instead of  **avatar** . It will work.

Comment: But again. How can I change it from being something like :user_file_name to :content, and still have paperclip know that what I mean is _file_name?

Comment: This method worked best for me. But be careful you will have to edit your image paths on the file system or with your chosen image storage. [This may help to rename your paths.](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Changing-attachment-%3Apath)

Comment: @bswinnerton, it will never be :content only because its mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

When you run the `rails g migration add_avatar_columns_to_users`, you can write as you wrote. But if you want to change the column names, go to the migration file and change them as you want as following. Please don't migrate it untill and unless you change the columns.

```
class AddAvatarColumnsToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
   add_column :users, :your_file_name,:string
   add_column :users, :your_content_type, :string
   add_column :users, :your_file_size,:integer
   add_column :users, :yourfile_updated_at,:datetime
  end

  def self.down
   remove_column :users, :your_file_name
   remove_column :users, :your_content_type
   remove_column :users, :your_file_size
   remove_column :users, :yourfile_updated_at
  end
end
```

Now run `rake db:migrate`

The above will work for sure. And add your attachments accordinbly.

Comment: But will paperclip still know to write to that column in the database if it's not ending in _file_name?